# how to have double pointers inside a PHP class

Tags: php, oop

so, a class in PHP can set attributes as follows:

```
$this->attribute1 = 'something';
```

it can also have methods (functions)

```
Class myClass{
function dothis($param){ .. }
}
```

In dothis() I may need to set attributes such as $this->status='OK' etc. - but status is a child of the class, not of the function.  Is there anything in PHP that can have a "sub-pointer" so that I can say $this->dothis->status='OK' so that I'm saying "the status of this METHOD in this class is OK" ?

As a bonus it would be nice to do the following:

```
$myclass = new MyClass();
$result =$myclass->doSomething($value1);
$result2=$myclass->doSomething($value2);
echo $result->status;
echo $result2->status; //one may be OK, one may be bad.. as opposed to $myclass->status
```

In other words, I'm wanting to bind the status OK to that FUNCTION, not just that class.  I suppose I could simply do this with the same namespace as the function, but I'm wondering what is best practice on this.

Comment: "Status of a method" does not make sense. Methods don't have attributes.

Comment: you can embed objects in objects. e.g. `class mydbclass { function __construct() { $this->db = new PDO(...) }`, and then `$myclass->db->query(...)`

Comment: see the answer below.  for complex methods that was what I was wanting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow entirely what you're asking, but your example seems clear:

```
$myclass = new MyClass();
$result =$myclass->doSomething($value1);
$result2=$myclass->doSomething($value2);
echo $result->status;
echo $result2->status;
```

It's very simple.  Just return from `doSomething()` with an object that has a status property.

```
Class MyClass() {
  function doSomething($val) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->status = 'OK';
    return $obj;
  }
}
```

Comment: `$this->obj` would make more sense. `$obj` would just get trashed when the method returns, since it's just a local variable.

Comment: @MarcB I forgot to return.  Fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: well, the intent of the function might be to return something else. But if not, this is what I'd consider to be the best way

Comment: Also I'd like to confirm that if the method name was doSomething(), then it would be ok to also have that same namespace (doSomething) as a object in that method, i.e. set $this->doSomething=new stdClass(); $this->doSomething->status='OK'; --- that way there is no ambiguity

Comment: @SamuelFullman You're throwing around a lot of terms incorrectly and it's really confusing me as to what you are trying to do.  Whatever you return is what matters here.  Why would you want to name a property the same as a function?

Comment: @Brad back in the days of FOP and say I had a function called sql_parse_query(), if I needed to store settings or data I would occasionally set a variable global $sql_parse_query in side, and add settings as array values.  One less thing to think about.  As far as throwing out terms, that's a function (pun somewhat intended) of my not knowing the term to use.  I'll make an effort to edit in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: @SamuelFullman If I had an array of settings, I would store it in `$this->_settings`.